# making the subversion revision number visible in my R scripts

Tags: svn, r

I'm putting this thing in my source(s)...  (right, for now it's just one, plus the test scripts).

```
REVISION = (function(x) substring(x, first=7, last=nchar(x)-2))("$Rev: 8727 $")
```

but how do "real" R programmers do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a pretty good solution. A regular expression may be more robust in case you fewer or more digits: swap the beginnning `$Rev :` and the trailing `$` for empty strings and you should have the revision left.

The only problem with the per-file properties is that they only update when this file itself is updated by subversion.

For that reason (and many others), consider making a local package.  Your DESCRIPTION file will a) change often enough for the new version number and b) can simply be extended by new fields you simply add e.g.

```
Revision: $Rev$
```

You can read the content from R via `read.dcf()` after which you can then do your trick of stripping the dollar signs and colon, or use a regular expression.

Comment: did not yet know the read.dcf function.  quite useful, thanks!

Comment: the problem "which is the highest revision number in this subdirectory" is probably best solved with a script that will put the highest number into a variable (defined in a file not under version control).  but allow me to extend the question...

Comment: not really extended, it's a different question...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888151

Comment: about reg.ex and my solution.  I tested it for un-substituted "$Rev$" as well as for less or more digits.

Comment: Does `svnversion` in the directory give the revision of the directory itself?  If and when you run `svn update`, that should be the current revision.  Or am I misunderstanding what you are after?

Comment: in Python I got used to having a __version__ variable in each module.  so after importing a module x.y, I can ask x.y.__version__ and have an idea of whether I'm using the latest version of the module.  I'm after something similar in R.  so: is there a way to associate a library to its version, so that this association is visible in the environment when I loaded the library?